# ASP.NET MVC ActionLink in jquery-tmpl template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates

I have a jquery-tmpl defined:

```
<script id="postTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
     <div class="div-msg-actions-inner">
          @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Post", new { postId = "${PostId}" }, new { @class = "button" })
          @Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Reply", "Post", new { topicId = "${TopicId}" }, new { @class = "button" })
     </div>
 </script>
```

The action link results in the "$" being encoded into "%24".  Is there a way around this so the ID in my action link will get replaced correctly?

Comment: I would, but the answers I got I don't find acceptable... I've never actually used the solutions offered.

Comment: Ok fair enough. But as you've already asked 7 questions and didn't get valuable answers you should maybe rephrase your questions. They will **(1)** get once again on the first page on stackoverflow and **(2)** have a better chance of getting answered. I try to polish my questions to get answers. And sometimes answer them myself when none of provided solutions were good and I end up using my own one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Post", new { postId = "999" }, new { @class = "post-button", })
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Reply", "Post", new { topicId = "888" }, new { @class = "reply-button" })

...

$("#postTemplate").text($("#postTemplate").text().replace("999", "${PostId}"));
$("#postTemplate").text($("#postTemplate").text().replace("888", "${TopicId}"));
```

This is the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 4):

Continue sending route value parameter the same, but Put this script in the end of your layout. it will replace all the ${propName} strings back in all templates in every page.

```
 $("script[type='text/x-jQuery-tmpl']").text(function (i, oldText) {
               return oldText.replace(/(%24%7B.+?%7D)&amp;/gi, "{$1}&")
                             .replace(/%24%7B(.+?)%7D/gi, "$${$1}");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this is to skip the ActionLink Helper and use a simple HTML anchor tag e.g.

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/Post/Edit/${PostId}")'>Post</a>
<a href='@Url.Content("~/Post/Reply/${TopicId}")'>Reply</a>
```

Not ideal I know but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `Html.Raw` with `Url.Action`

Have you tried using `Html.Raw` in combination with `Url.Action`? So instead of creating links with `Html.ActionLink` you rather generate regular HTML and don't encode URL of that particular link/anchor.

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Edit", "Post", new { postId = "${PostId}"}, new { @class = "button" }))">Edit</a>
```

This should keep the template variable inside your template.

### Using `Html.Raw` with `Html.ActionLink`

I suppose you've tried this:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Post", new { postId = "${PostId}" }, new { @class = "button" }))
```

Comment: I tried this and it was the same result.  I think the "$" is getting encoded by the Url.Action and Html.ActionLink methods, so I don't think Html.Raw helps.