# html.actionlink values in jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Is there any way i can retrieve the values of `actionlink` in jquery?

For example: I would want the values 4 and "abc" from

`html.actionlink("action","controller",new {id=4,name="abc"},new {@class="a"})` in jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent of ActionLink accessable from javascript. A possible solution is based on string replacement. You prepare the link and send it through your view. In javascript then replace its dynamic parts. See this answer:

[ASP.NET MVC ActionLink in jquery-tmpl template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889465/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-in-jquery-tmpl-template)

Comment: Actually i passed the data as id and accessed the class in jqeury to retrieve the value. Kinda worked for my situation!!
    @html.actionlink("link","action","controller",null,new{@class="a",@id=item.id})

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLink will render an actual link on the page, so all you can do is use jQuery to read the `href` property of that link.

i.e.

```
$('.a').attr('href');
```

Comment: It returns the link. But what i need is the id and name from the link. i need to pass these data to the controller and receive the result to load it in the division.

Comment: I can search for the substring and use it but is there is any other way i can do this?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the URL that is generated? If it is blank, there may be a problem with your code.

Comment: Ok, so based on your action link, you should have `<a href="http://localhost:1042/chmenu/edit?oid=1&name=abc" class="a">text</a>` rendered to the browser. As a result, the above jQuery should work, however it depends on when you are calling it. Add `alert($('.a').attr('href'));` to your `ready` function.

Comment: Also, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068.aspx for the correct usage, as your example does not include the text to create the link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get all attribute values of action link if you know its class name or id,

following is example how you can do it with jquery if you know action links class,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          // Get id of action Link
          var id = $(".a").attr('id');
          // Get href of link
          var hreflink = $(".a").attr('href');
          // Get href of title
          var linktitle = $(".a").attr('title');
          alert(id);
          alert(hreflink);
          alert(linktitle);
        });
    </script>
```